# javascript new Date() returns invalid value

Tags: javascript

This is javaScript code, new Date() returns invalid value.
Do I need change the date format before pass it to new Date()?

```
new Date("25-Feb-17");
```

Comment: Works for me in chrome, I always find it safer to create date objects like `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)` as then I know they're right

Comment: what else you expect?

Comment: It should not. Just tried and its working fine here : https://jsfiddle.net/dtppbuw4/

Comment: @binariedMe it's browser dependent...that is not a valid date string. Try it in firefox. you probably tried in chrome which is a lot more tolerant to invalid dates

Comment: alert(new Date("25-Feb-17")) works fine in Chrome. But not in IE

Comment: Eric..it is simply not a valid date string and could have been easily researched. There are lots and lots of resources on web that provide you with the various valid versions

Comment: Are you open to use any third party date library ? If yes then you can go for https://momentjs.com library.

Comment: [how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 3):

[On MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), you can read the following about this particular `Date` constructor:

> **Note:** parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

If you want the constructor to work correctly across all browsers, either use one of its other variants (also described on the linked MDN page) or at least reformat your date string to be compliant with the [ISO8601 date representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The latter option isn't 100% guaranteed to work though since JavaScript uses a slightly simplified convention for representing dates as strings; you might find corner cases that will fail.

Also, as per the quoted note, there's a caveat. Using simplified date formats such as `"2017-02-25"` will be treated as UTC, but then internally translated to your local timezone. Assuming you're on the western hemisphere, the final result will be February 24th instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its not working on Firefox, tested on Chrome and worked fine so I suggest you to use the standard Date object creation as follows:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Comment: There are lots of other valid ways to do this using Date object

Comment: True, that's why I'm suggesting the methodology I would use, OP can choose whatever he prefers.